# ¿Cómo hacer que un <input> ocupe todo el ancho disponible?

Tags: html, css, css3, php7

(Editado)
Buen día, espero puedan orientarme en cómo resolver mi duda.
Antes que nada, debo mencionar que estoy usando grid.
Adjunto mi estructura HTML

```
<div class="grillaCotizacion">
    <div class="div1 form-item">
        <input type="text" id="precio" autocomplete="off" required name="precio">
        <label for="precio">precio $:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2 form-item">
        <input type="text" id="total" autocomplete="off" required name="total">
        <label for="total">total $:</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adjunto mis hojas de estilo:

```
.grillaCotizacion {  
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 20% 80%; /* Aquí le estoy dando un ancho al primer div un 20%, al segundo div un 80% */
 grid-gap: 20px;
}

.div1 {
background: #800303;    
}

.div2 {
 background: #01447e;
}

 .form-item {
  position     : relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-item input {
 display   : block;
 height    : 45px;
 background: transparent;
 border    : solid 1px #ccc;
 transition: all .3s ease;
 padding   : 0 15px;
 font-size : 16px;
  }

.form-item input:focus {
 border-color: blue
 }

.form-item label {
 position      : absolute;
 cursor        : text;
 z-index       : 2;
 top           : 13px;
 left          : 10px;
 font-size     : 12px;
 font-weight   : bold;
 background    : #fff;
 padding       : 0 10px;
 color         : #999;
 transition    : all .3s ease;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }

.form-item input:focus+label,
.form-item input:valid+label{
 font-size: 11px;
 top      : -5px
 }

.form-item input:focus+label{
 color: blue
 }
```

Bien, esa es mi estructura HTML y mis estilos CSS 3, ¿podrían decirme qué me hace falta? o ¿dónde estoy haciendo mal?
La verdad no sé cómo hacerle para que los `input` ocupen el ancho disponible, a los `div` les puse un color para ver el ancho disponible que sobra, pero mis `input` no rellenan ese espacio, solamente quedan chicos y no se ajustan al ancho disponible, es decir, el primer `input` pertenece al `div1` que tiene un 20%, si se fijan bien, no alcanza a rellenar el espacio disponible: lo mismo pasa con el segundo `input`, que pertenece al `div2`.
No sé tanto de hojas d estilo.

Les adjunto dos imágenes del espacio sobrante que les estoy mencionando.
La primera es a pantalla completa, la segunda imagen es cuando la pantalla se hace chica.

Primera imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segunda imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué esperas conseguir?

Comment: Por favor, agrega todo el codigo que estás mostrando, faltan contenedores que muestras en la imagen.

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te paso la solucion y te explico

Resulta que primero que todo tienes que resetear los estilos css que tienen los navegadores por defecto, para ello muchos desarrolladores usamos plantillas ya creadas como la de [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) para hacer este proceso mas facil y rapido.

Basicamente el ajuste que debes de hacer siempre como minimo es el siguiente.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px; // 1rem;
}
```

Sobre todo la propiedad `box-sizing: border-box` nos ayuda a que las bordes, margenes y padding que tienen las cajas por defecto, desaparezcan y nos permitan tener un diseño mas fluido, te dejo un articulo mas completo acerca del tema en [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Finalmente debes de setear los estilos de todos los inputs para que tengan la propiedad `display: block;` & `width: 100%;` esto hara que ocupen siempre el 100% de su contenedor padre.

Sin mas divagacion te dejo la solucion

**Posdata:** Le agregue unos estilos a los bordes de los `inputs` cuando esta en su estado `:focus` para que puedas notar la diferencia

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.grillaCotizacion {
  display: grid;
  /* Aquí le estoy dando un ancho al primer div un 20%, al segundo div un 80% */
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
}

.div1 {
  background: #800303;
}

.div2 {
  background: #01447e;
}

.form-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.form-item input {
  background: transparent;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-item input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #02fffd !important;
  outline: transparent;
}

.form-item label {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: text;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 13px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.form-item input:focus + label,
.form-item input:valid + label {
  font-size: 11px;
  top: -5px;
}

.form-item input:focus + label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grillaCotizacion">
    <div class="div1 form-item">
        <input type="text" id="precio" autocomplete="off" required name="precio">
        <label for="precio">precio $:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="div2 form-item">
        <input type="text" id="total" autocomplete="off" required name="total">
        <label for="total">total $:</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Saludos !

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó bastante tu respuesta, me aclaró bastante tu explicación, además de la documentación que me proporcionaste.

Answer (score 2):

Implementa el autofill

```
   .form1 {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:  repeat( auto-fill, minmax(350px, 1fr) ); /*Aquí hago la división de dos columnas */
 grid-column-gap      : 20px;
 grid-row-gap         : 30px;  
 background : #fff;
 margin     : 0 auto;  
}
```

en la documentacion de css nos dice

> auto-fill RELLENA la fila con tantas columnas como pueda caber. Por lo
> tanto, crea columnas implícitas cada vez que una nueva columna puede
> encajar, porque está tratando de LLENAR la fila con tantas columnas
> como pueda. Las columnas recién agregadas pueden y pueden estar
> vacías, pero seguirán ocupando un espacio designado en la fila.

Por favor, verifica si con esto se consigue lo que estás buscando. Y déjanos tu comentario.

Comment: No consigo lo que estoy buscando, de hecho tuve que agregar una clase a mis <input> y en las hojas de estilo les doy un ancho de width: 350px; respectivamente, pero aún así el  <input> sale del grid.

Comment: entiendo. por favor, puedes hacer una imagen referencial de lo que quisieras conseguir?

Comment: Ya hice la modificación a mi pregunta, y con unas ilustraciones para que puedan comprender mi duda.

Answer (score 1):

Pues si no entendi mal lo que puedes hacer para ocupar el ancho disponible del input es modifcar tu padding de la clase .form-item-input de la siguiente manera

```
.form-item input {
    display   : block;  
    height    : 45px;
    background: transparent;
    border    : solid 1px #ccc;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    padding   : 0 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: Buenas, si tratas de responder, debes dejar la solución al problema y la explicación del mismo. Mira [answer] para saber más al respecto. Por ahora, esta es una respuesta mala o de baja calidad.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agregué el padding al 100% y width al 100%, y se sale del grid.